# BitmapFactory.decodeResource Загрузка изображений

Tags: java, android

Есть класс DrawingImageView:

```
public class DrawingImageView extends View {

    private PointF point;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    Initialization init; //<---------------------

    public DrawingImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init = new Initialization(); <-------------------
    }

    public DrawingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                point = new PointF(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                point.set(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                point = null;
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (point != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 100, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(init.b01,10,10,paint);<------------
        }
    }
}
```

И Класс Initialization

```
public class Initialization extends Activity {
    Bitmap b01;

    public Initialization() {
        Bitmap b05 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.t02);
    }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь нарисовать через обьект класса init.b01 app крашиться. когда описываешь в самом классе DrawingImageView  все нормально. Как это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Загрузка изображений.BitmapFactory.decodeResource](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619171/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-bitmapfactory-decoderesource)

Comment: Не надо создавать одинаковые вопросы только потому, что первый не заметили. Его не заметили т.к. вы опечатались при проставлении меток к нему