# Загрузка изображений.BitmapFactory.decodeResource

Tags: android

Есть класс DrawingImageView :

```
class DrawingImageView extends View {
    Initialization init;
    private PointF point;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawingImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init = new Initialization(getContext());
    }

    public DrawingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(init.b01,10,10,paint);
    }
}
```

И Класс Initialization:

```
public class Initialization extends View {
    Bitmap b01;
    public Initialization(Context context) {
        super(context);
        b01 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.t02);
    }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь нарисовать через обьект класса init.b01 app крашиться. когда описываешь в самом классе DrawingImageView все нормально. Как это исправить?

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:758)
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:104)
at com.example.itsgonnabeme.simpledraw.DrawingImageView.onDraw(Dview.java:46)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13807)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12742)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3019)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2883)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3019)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2883)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12740)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3019)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2883)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13815)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2235)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12742)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12786)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1249)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2473)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2340)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2142)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawView(MainActivity.this));
    }
}
```

class DrawView:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Initialization init;
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init = new Initialization(getContext());
        paint  = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(init.t01,0,0,paint);
    }
}
```

class Initialization:

```
public class Initialization  extends View  {
    Bitmap t01;
        public Initialization(Context context) {
        super(context);
        t01 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.t02);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В андроиде нельзя ничего делать в конструкторах фрагментов и активити. Это нужно просто запомнить и никогда их не трогать. Вместо конструктора этих классов используйте их методы `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

В данном случае у вас `NPE` при попытке взять ресурсы не подсоединённой к контексту приложения активити

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52525/discussion-on-answer-by----bitmapfactory-decoderesourc).